# VARCHAR' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server, function, varchar

Here is my mssql function code.

```
 ALTER function [dbo].[UF_GetOrderProducts]
(
  @OrderId int
)
returns varchar(500)
as
begin

return
  (
  select CAST(VARCHAR(5),OP.ProductId)+'<br/>'
  from OrderProduct as OP

  where OP.OrderId = @OrderId
  for xml path(''), type
  ).value('.', 'varchar(500)')
end
```

It returns, `VARCHAR' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CAST(VARCHAR(5),OP.ProductId)
```

should be

```
CAST(OP.ProductId as VARCHAR(5))
```

See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).